# Tmux colors and theme not working correctly

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, colors, themes, tmux

I feel like i have tried everything, but just can't seem to get colors or a theme working properly in tmux. The colors or theme used seem to be those of the standard ubuntu terminal.

My .tmux.conf:

```
set-environment -g TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH '~/.tmux/plugins/'
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

... keybindings

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
set -g @plugin 'dracula/tmux' <- currently trying this one but have also tried catpuccin 
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-yank'

run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

[image: screenshot of terminal]

When i run `prefix + I` the plugins get installed however i dont see a mention of the theme.